# jQuery datepicker 'today' center position

Tags: jquery, datepicker, alignment

How do I align the **"today"** button at the `center` position of the `button pane` in **jQuery datepicker**?

I have tried editing the css (ui-datepicker-buttonpane with `text-align: center`) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you please provide us with a http://jsfiddle.net with all of your code so that we can better assist you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for jQuery Datepicker UI the css applied on the Today button by default is like:

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current {
    float: left;
 }
```

Add `margin-left:35%` to it for bring it in the center.

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 35%;
}
```

Here is the screen-shot:

[image]